# Virtualhost apache set document root but serve other files not in root

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, virtualhost

I have this scenario where I need the document root to be public but also the folder test should be served from the same domain. I achieved this using RewriteConditions inside  but when redirected i dont want the folder to be shown so basically when document root is set to public it serves public and if I go to browser I can see that, but if I use rewrite rules it redirects to public but the domain is switched to domain.com/public/(whatever_file) . Is it possible to do that just with virtual hosts and not the rewrite. Ah also I do not want to create more VirtualHosts. cause these to folder will be related.

[image]